# Eclipse RCP: add menus/commands on Ubuntu failing

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to create an RCP application following this [article](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html) but failing to add the main [menu](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#commands_menu). Is this a bug or am i missing something.

I'm using:

Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers, Version: Helios Service Release 2, Build id: 20110218-0911 on Ubuntu 11.04

java version "1.6.0_24" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode).

My plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         id="application"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
      <application>
         <run
               class="my.project.Application">
         </run>
      </application>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
      <perspective
            name="RCP Perspective"
            class="my.project.Perspective"
            id="my.project.perspective">
      </perspective>
   </extension>
   <extension
         id="product"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
      <product
            application="my.project.application"
            name="My Project">
         <property
               name="windowImages"
               value="icons/alt_window_16.gif,icons/alt_window_32.gif">
         </property>
      </product>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            defaultHandler="my.project.commands.ExitHandler"
            id="my.project.commands.Exit"
            name="Exit">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
         <menu
               id="fileMenu"
               label="File"
               mnemonic="F">
            <command
                  commandId="my.project.commands.Exit"
                  label="Exit"
                  mnemonic="x"
                  style="push"
                  tooltip="Exits the application">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with Spring Tool Suite in latest Ubuntu.
Problem was solved using answers from this link:
http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-108599.html

I think is a bug in ubuntu.